# give Wrong date while conversion local time to UTC time android?

Tags: android, date, datetime, time

i am using time conversion Local to UTC and Utc to local,while selecting Time 12:00 PM local time (Sydney Australia) it convert time 01:00 in Utc But it should be 02:00 , while converting UTC to Local It correct time But Date will be Next day date, while selecting other time it give correct output
please give some solution 
thank you

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - your description isn't *nearly* clear enough. (In particular, the date matters as well... we need complete input data and output data.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertLocalTimeToUTC(String p_city, String p_localDateTime) throws Exception{

String lv_dateFormateInUTC="";//Will hold the final converted date
Datelv_localDate = null;
Stringlv_localTimeZone ="";
SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter;
SimpleDateFormat lv_parser;

//Temp for testing(mapping of cities and timezones will eventually be in a properties file
if(p_city.equals("LON")){
lv_localTimeZone="Europe/London";
}else if(p_city.equals("NBI")){
lv_localTimeZone="EAT";
}else if(p_city.equals("BRS")){
lv_localTimeZone="Europe/Brussels";
}else if(p_city.equals("MNT")){
lv_localTimeZone="America/Montreal";
}else if(p_city.equals("LAS")){
lv_localTimeZone="PST";
}

//create a new Date object using the timezone of the specified city
lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
lv_parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));
lv_localDate = lv_parser.parse(p_localDateTime);

//Set output format prints "2007/10/25  18:35:07 EDT(-0400)"
lv_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z'('Z')'");
lv_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));

System.out.println("convertLocalTimeToUTC: "+p_city+": "+" The Date in the local time zone " + lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate));

//Convert the date from the local timezone to UTC timezone
lv_formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
lv_dateFormateInUTC = lv_formatter.format(lv_localDate);
System.out.println("convertLocalTimeToUTC: "+p_city+": "+" The Date in the UTC time zone " + lv_dateFormateInUTC);


return lv_dateFormateInUTC;
}
```